# Замена значения innerText = InnerText

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая добавляет в текст значение атрибута. Но при записи

```
const rez = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach((item) => {
  **item.innerText** = ${item.getAttribute('data-test-id')} **${item.innerText}**
})}
```

не работает,

а когда

```
const rez = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').forEach((item) => { 
  **item.innerText** = `${item.getAttribute('data-test-id')} **${item.textContent}** 
})
```

все ок.

Comment: Вероятно, работающая запись - правильная, а другая - нет. Но в вопросе - обе неработающие.

Answer (score 1):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.list-item')].forEach( item => {
    item.textContent += item.getAttribute('data-test-id');
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/efimleonid/jxoqe2vu/2/

Comment: функции идентичны, разница в том что в работающей  item.innetText = item.tetxContent а в неработающей item.innerText = item.innerText . Хотя по сути работать должны оба варианта. Может есть ньанся, когда переменная сама на себя ссылается.